# Add values to a vector to make a consecutive vector in R

Tags: r, rstudio

I have several vectors that look like this:

```
v1 <- c(1,2,4)
v2 <- c(3,5,8)
v3 <- c(4)
```

This is just a small sample of them. I'm trying to figure out a way to add values to each of them to make them all consecutive vectors. So that at the end, they look like this:

```
v1 <- c(1,2,3,4)
v2 <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
v3 <- c(1,2,3,4)
```

So "3" is added to the first vector, "1","2","4","6","7" is added to the second and so forth. I have several hundred vectors that look like this so I'm trying to figure out a solution that would scale/be automated.

Comment: try `seq(max(v1)` and same for other variables

Comment: has nothing to do with rstudio, please remove tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `seq` and `max`

```
  seq(max(v1))
```

For multiple vectors, we can loop

```
 lapply(mget(paste0('v',1:3)), function(x) seq(max(x)))
 #$v1
 #[1] 1 2 3 4

 #$v2
 #[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8

 #$v3
 #[1] 1 2 3 4
```